# How to perform recursive find in unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I have an issue where I have a zip file which contains other zip files as well.Example abc.zip present in /home/data directory contains def.zip which again contains gef.zip.
So, currently I am using below command in unix:

```
find /home/data -depth -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -n {} \; -delete
```

This command unzip the file but leaves the next zip file that is available after it unzipped abc.zip which is true as it goes through directory only once.

please can anyone suggest how to loop through find command again and again until there is no zip file present in /home/data directory using unix shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all robust, but you might just try creating a file whenever you unzip a file and check for the existence.  eg:

```
while
  rm -f /tmp/sentinel
  find /home/data -depth -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -n {} \; -exec touch /tmp/sentinel \; -delete
  test -f /tmp/sentinel
do : ; done
```